# In my spring project, I use Elasticsearch as a backend database. I want to know how to seperate an index name and a data model

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

This is a general way to declare a document model and request a query.
As you can see the index name is binded to the data class.
I want to pass an index name so that it can be configurable.  Any ideas?

```
@Document(indexName = "my_index")
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String name;

}
```

```
earchResponse<Product> response = esClient.search(s -> s
    .index("products") 
    .query(q -> q      
        .match(t -> t   
            .field("name")  
            .query(searchText)
        )
    ),
    Product.class      
);
```